# Steps in subclassing UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, customization

I would like to subclass the UINavigationController to get some more freedom in regards to the appearance of the controller.

I have some graphics for the different parts, bars, buttons, text etc.
Looking at the UINavigationController header file I get little help, I don't know where to start out.

I have never subclassed/overridden a UIKit component before, it seems it is a bit like playing Sherlock Holmes.

**What is the approach?**

**How do I know what to override to get a a specific piece of graphics "injected" the correct place?**

**Do I need to subclass UINavigationBar, UIBarButtonItem etc. etc to get the complete customized look?**

**How do I know if something is off limits in regards to being approved by Apple?**

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, I have only been able to find examples of changing small parts of the controller, not a full customization by subclassing.
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks:)

Comment: For what it’s worth, you’ll probably do better to write a custom navigation controller from the ground up.

Comment: You can hint from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69733545/3647325

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should NOT extend UINavigationController.

**As of iOS 6, this information is outdated.** From the Xcode 5 docs:
*You generally use this class as-is but in iOS 6 and later you may subclass to customize the class behavior.*

**Original outdated information follows:**

From the documentation:

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances of it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content.

You may want to consider creating categories or subclassing your UINavigationBar and potentially creating custom UIButtons that you use to create UIBarButtonItems.

Whenever you deal with a UI component that extends from UIView what you should consider doing is subclassing and overriding

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

There are plenty of examples here on stackoverflow or on Apple's official documentation site.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I can see that when searching for how to override there are tons of results, but very few and no good ones when looking for subclassing. I did a category in the UINavigationBar, this changes the background, Will I have to do this for UINavigationController, UIBarButtonItem etc.etc. to change buttons and fonts?

Comment: Hi Ricki,

1. Do not extend UINavigationController, nor UIBarButtonItem.
2. When creating the UIBarButtonItem use the initWithCustomView initalizer which will allow you to prepare and use whatever view you need (in which you can draw any text, font, image, etc).
Cheers

Comment: Thanks Nick:) After having wrapped it nicely in categories and a utility class, I am really glad I took the advise and didn't try to build my own or extend it. I can now change the titleLabel and background on the navigationBar and use my custom buttons as BarButtomItems.

Comment: Apple's documentation is changed. I think this answer should be updated.

Answer (score 55):

Now you can subclass UINavigationController, see updated documentation:

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and also makes it easier for the user to navigate that content. This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.

[UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Actually I think it's better to point out this change in a comment to the answer marked as "correct".
I think I'll do it...