# Change UINavigationBar Color for One View Controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller with a custom background navigation bar. I am using iOS 5's UINavigationBar "appearance" attribute to set the background image.

I am doing so in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions app delegate method in order to change the background image across all nav bars. Trouble is, I need to change the navigation bar color to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent for one single view controller.

How can I do this without having to go back and change every single view controller?

Comment: Have you tried to make its copy and to assign it when you need?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean here, can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UINavigationController and have the popViewControllerAnimated method of your subclass reset the background image/color then call super's popViewControllerAnimated.

This assumes you are using a UINavigationController, which I think you are.

Comment: Aren't you not supposed to subclass UINavigationController? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029959/steps-in-subclassing-uinavigationcontroller