# Swift 3 - Add navigation items to UINavigationController subclass

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a subclass of `UINavigationController` called `NavController`. The reason why I'm subclassing it is because I'm building the UI programmatically and for this specific navigation class I need a specific button on the left/right portion of its navigationBar.

This is what I have in the subclass:

```
import UIKit
class NavController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.navi
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

    // tearing my hair out here
    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))


    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh

}

func doSomething() {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Is it right accessing the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` from `self`?
I'm running out of hair.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ya you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick anwser: No.

`navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` is property of the view controllers in UINavigationController, not the navigation controller itself.

e.g:

```
let firstVC = UIViewController()
let firstBarItem = UIBarButtonItem()
firstVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = firstBarItem
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
```

The navigation controller now display `firstBarItem`

```
let secondVC = UIViewController()
let secondBarItem = UIBarButtonItem()
secondVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = secondBarItem

nc.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

The navigation controller now display `secondBarItem`

If you pop back to `firstVC`, it will automatically display `firstBarItem`

Comment: I get that. So how can I access it from within the navigation controller itself?

Comment: You can get the last view controller (the current displayed view controller) from the navigation controller's child view controllers: `nc.viewControllers.last?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`

Comment: So should I repeat the same code to add the buttons in each child viewController?

Comment: If it just takes 1 line, then it's ok. Otherwise there are many ways to reuse your code such as: subclass UIViewController, create a category, ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the `refresh` button in the navigation bar? But the current code can't do that, right? Let use this code:

```
if let navigationItem = navigationBar.items?.first {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Do your customization here
        if let rootVC = self.viewControllers.first {
            self.addCancelButton(rootVC: rootVC)
        }
    }

    func addCancelButton(rootVC: UIViewController) {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "cancel"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(btnClose))
        barButton.tintColor = .black
        rootVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    @objc func btnClose() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Below Code is for Left Side UIBarButtonItem for Navigation Bar
let leftItemBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(leftBarButtonTapped))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItemBarButton

func leftBarButtonTapped() {
print("Left Bar Button Item")
}

// Below Code is for Right Side UIBarButtonItem for Navigation Bar

let rightItemBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonTapped))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItemBarButton

func rightBarButtonTapped() {
print("Right Bar Button Item")
}
```

There are also different methods if you want to put image in navigation bar using UIBarButtonItem methods

Comment: What's the difference between this and the code in my question?